# Removing entity queue entries from a view

Tags: views, 8, blocks

I have a list of 100 projects. I have set 10 projects as featured projects using Entity Queue module.

I have a projects page that shows has two views:

- First view: 10 projects from entity queue
- Second view: all 100 projects

The issue is the 10 projects are showing up twice on the page, is there a way to remove the entity queue featured projects from the second view?

Any help?

Comment: On views prerender or query alter or some similar hook you could load the view with the 10 entries, get their entity IDs and then load the other view and unset these IDs from its query.

Comment: @leymannx 
This is very helpful thank you. I just have one more requirement though. I have an exposed option to filter projects by state. It doesnt work with the featured projects though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that should be easy enough. In your view with the 100 projects you need to:

1)Add a relationship to the entity queue but DON'T make it required

2)That will make a filter called "Content In Queue" be available for you to add

3) Set that filter to "No"

And that's it any entities that are in the queue won't come out in that view now

Comment: This is very helpful thank you. I just have one more requirement though. I have an exposed option to filter projects by state. It doesnt work with the featured projects though. Any thoughts?